# Split one row into multiple rows according to `sum` column

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.6

[schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73cbd0/1)

In table `track_play_counts` there is a column named `play_count` which is a sum of individual `track_play_count`. How to split the `play_count` column into different rows which will have `play_count` value as 1 only? The table contains thousands of data, So I can not do it manually.

For example, if `play_count` is 10 then there should be 10 rows with 1 `play_count`. How can I achieve it using mysql or laravel?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because of changing requirements of the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to create a new table which has one row for each individual `track_play_count`.

```
CREATE TABLE new_play_counts (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) AS
SELECT track_id, 1 AS play_count
FROM (SELECT n10.n*10 + n.n AS num
      FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
                          UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6
                          UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) n10
      JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
                          UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6
                          UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) n
      ) numbers
JOIN track_play_counts p ON p.play_count > numbers.num
ORDER BY p.Id, numbers.num
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d45387008200f13e0eaa572e45550252)

**Notes**

1. I've assumed that the maximum value of `play_count` is 99, if it is higher than that you would need to increase the size of the `numbers` table by `JOIN`ing another digit to it.
2. I've also assumed that you would want to give each row in the new table a distinct id value, if not, you would remove `(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)` from the first line of the query and change the `SELECT` to `SELECT id, track_id, 1 AS play_count`

Comment: Thanks for reply, solved problem using laravel eloquent query.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it to help other people who might have the same problem.